# Is it possible to develop for Android Oreo under Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to develop for Android under Visual Studio 2015. I need to use some of the features that are new in Android Oreo (8.0, API 26). I have Android SDK 8.0 installed, but Android 8.0 is not available as a target version for my project under VS2015. (Android 7.0 is the latest.) I don't wish to upgrade to VS2017, because I have a stable development platform right now and don't want to risk that.

This article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/platform/oreo?tabs=vswin gives clear instructions on how to set up Visual Studio for development for Android Oreo. It says to "downgrade SDK tools to 25" if using VS 2015, which implies that it is possible to develop for Android Oreo under VS2015. However, it also says that "version 15.5 or later of Visual Studio is required". I understand that version 15.5 is VS 2017, not 2015 (the latest version for VS2015 being 14.0). Is that correct? Is it actually possible to develop for Android Oreo under VS 2015? And if so, can anyone tell me how to set things up?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps to use Android Oreo API(26-27) inside vs2015:

1. install Java 8 SE Development kit (Windows x64), here there is the link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html;
2. Install through Android SDK Manager the SDK Platform for API 26 and 27;
3. Update your Xamarin Tools for Visual Studio to 4.9 version (it's the last stable release)
4. Open Vs2015 and go inside TOOLS->OPTION->XAMARIN->ANDROID SETTINGS and set the Java Development Kit path to the folder of new Java SDK (it will be something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181)
5. Restart Vs2015 and open your Android project: now inside project options you will see also Android Oreo in destination framework dropdownlist.

I suggest you to set Android Oreo 8.1 cause some dll seem to have troubles with 8.0 (Api 26) during project compilation.
You can also have another problem: when you will try to archieve the output to produce the apk package the 'DISTRIBUTE' button seems to be frozen (it's a xamarin bug, here you can find more informations: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/123412/archive-distribute-button-not-working). If you will have the same situation you can manually sign the apk file and create it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/manually-signing-the-apk).

Comment: Thanks so much for making the time to answer my question! I can now actually select Android 8.1 as my target version under VS 2015. You have helped me hugely! Apologies for taking so long to get back to you. I was side-tracked into something else.

Comment: Don't be worried,  i'm happy you fixed this situation